# How to run selenium-side-runner ignoring SSL certification errors

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

When running a selenium script in the IDE plugin it works fine as I can start the browser with an argument to ignore SSL errors.

When running the script in the selenium-side-runner I can not figure out what and how to pass it trough the command line interface.

I have tried bot h chrome and firefox

```
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome chromeOptions.args=[ignore-certificate-errors]" script.side
```

both generate error message relating to the SSL certificate being absent

Answer (score 2):

You can use the capability acceptInsecureCerts=true
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome acceptInsecureCerts=true" script.side